# Excel data distribution with Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am not good at English, so sentences may be wrong.

I want to distribute excel files prepared in advance to users. Is it possible to realize such a system with shiny? No problem with .zip.
Thank you

#### ui.R

```
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    downloadButton('downloadData', 'Excel Download')
  )
)
```

#### server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "distribution.xlsx",
    content = "distribution_excel"
  )
})
```

[image: file organization]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and you were nearly there. Below is a minimal working example. I assume that your `.xlsx` file is located in the same folder as your `app.R`. Notice that I have created the app in a single R file as opposed to two separate files.

The trick to getting the file to download is to use a function for the content inside of `downloadHandler()`. Specifically we are using the base function `file.copy()`. Clicking the button should now download the file: `distribution.xlsx`. This file can obviously be exchanged with a zip file.

If you want different users to access different Excel files, you can write an additional function inside of your server function that passes the file argument to the `downloadHandler()`.

```
# Load packages ----
pkgs <- c("shiny")
invisible(lapply(pkgs, require, character.only = TRUE))

# Set up the UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Define your download button
  downloadButton(
    outputId = "downloadData",
    label = "Excel Download"
  )
)

# Set up the server side ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Define the download handler with function() for content. 
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "distribution.xlsx",
    content = function(file) {
      file.copy("distribution.xlsx", file)
    }
  )
}

# Combine into an app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for, do you mind accepting it?

Comment: I didn't know it for the first time, I'm sorry. is this OK?

Comment: Yeah, that's perfect.